# Use a type as alias for generics with constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have several generic functions that use the same generic type that is bounded to a given type and defaulted to other type.

Something like this:

```
function pepe<TInterpolationMap extends object = StringMap>(key: string, ownOptions: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string): string = { 
  /* code */
}

function kaka<TInterpolationMap extends object = StringMap>(key: string, ownOptions: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string): string = { 
  /* code */
}
```

and more functions with the same signature.

Can I do something like put that declaration inside an abstraction like this:

```
type boundedType<T> = <T extends object = StringMap>
```

so the method's declarations could be written like:

```
function pepe<boundedType<TInterpolationMap>>(key: string, ownOptions: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string): string = { 
  /* code */
}

function kaka<boundedType<TInterpolationMap>>(key: string, ownOptions: TOptions<TInterpolationMap> | string): string = { 
  /* code */
}
```

This not only will spare me some writing it also will allow to change the constrained generic's parameters (I mean: object and StringMap) in one place.

Comment: No, there is no support for anything like this.  Do you want an answer just saying "no, sorry"?  I can't find a relevant feature request asking for it so I don't have an authoritative source for the lack of the feature (it's not like there's a document listing all the features that *don't* exist).

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the quick reply! jajaj it has been long time since our last conversation! how you doing?. I'm afraid someone edited my question and remove and important part of it that explans my motivation and some background context. Thanks for your anwser and we can consider the question answered. If you think this thing could be taken as a feature request, please be my guest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no support in TypeScript for abstracting a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) or a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) into a reusable structure.  The closest feature request I can find is [microsoft/TypeScript#41470](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41470) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#23188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23188) which ask for a way to declare local [`type` aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases); if such a feature existed you *might* be able to leverage it to help here, but maybe not.  If you're really interested in pursuing this you might want to file an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) requesting the feature, keeping in mind that you shouldn't expect it to be implemented quickly, if ever.

Comment: I will keep that in mind! Probably we will see again on github side again but I don't wanna bother you guys too much in the immediate term. Keep up doing a good work. I will be always grateful for "dressing" javascript with java's outfit and making the life easier to anyone.